# Find the last colored line in a Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using colored cells to make section in Excel sheets with full colored lines.

I'm looking for a way to easily get the address of the las horizontal line fully colored on backgroud.

The way I looking for is with the Find method but I can't make it

```
With Application.FindFormat
    .Clear
    .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End With
```

`cell = .Find(What:="", After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), SearchFormat:=True)`

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

### Last Fully Colored Row Address

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetLastColoredRowAddressTEST()
    Debug.Print GetLastColoredRowAddress(Range("A1:M20"))
    ' Caution! When using for whole worksheet use this:
    Debug.Print GetLastColoredRowAddress(Sheet1.UsedRange.EntireRow)
End Sub

Function GetLastColoredRowAddress( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As String
    
    With Application.FindFormat
        .Clear
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = rCount To 1 Step -1
        Set rCell = rg.Rows(r).Find(What:="", _ 
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchFormat:=True)
        If rCell Is Nothing Then
            GetLastColoredRowAddress = rg.Rows(r).Address
            Exit For
        End If
    Next r
    
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    
End Function
```

### Edit

- Here's a worksheet version. Of course, you should rename the functions as you see fit.

```vb
Sub GetLastWorksheetColoredRowAddressTEST()
    Debug.Print GetLastWorksheetColoredRowAddress(Sheet1)
End Sub

Function GetLastWorksheetColoredRowAddress( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet) _
As String
    
    With Application.FindFormat
        .Clear
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
    
    With ws.UsedRange.EntireRow
        Dim rCell As Range
        Dim r As Long
        For r = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set rCell = .Rows(r).Find(What:="", _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchFormat:=True)
            If rCell Is Nothing Then
                GetLastWorksheetColoredRowAddress = .Rows(r).Address
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    End With
    
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    
End Function
```

Comment: The idea is to search each row, from bottom to top, to find `xlNone`. If `xlNone` is found then go to the previous row (Note that one `xlNone` is enough to discard the whole row). If `xlNone` is not found, the desired column is found. It is too slow to loop through each cell.

Comment: Thats a clever algorithm, but a quite slow on large set on data.

Comment: If the whole left side of the worksheet is colored, it will be slow, but then you can use `SearchDirection:=xlPrevious` to start with the right side. Could you maybe share a screenshot of your worksheet? This has to be super fast.

Comment: I've just reopened this script and finally arrived to make it faster. I have inverted the loop so it starts searching the sheet from the top :     `For r = 1 To rCount Step 1`